# Not able to see exact error message at Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I have the almost same issue that asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63439021/handling-errors-with-redux-toolkit)

I have tried to use the same solution but could not manage it.

[image]

All I want to see is to get correct error message. And I have written this part.

```
export const createNewC = createAsyncThunk(
  'c/',
  async (input: c, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      return (await companiesService.create(input)) as c;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('here');
      const response = (error as AxiosError).response as AxiosResponse;
      console.log('here2', response.data);
      let errorMessage = '';
      errorMessage = response.data.message;
      console.log('here3');
      console.log(errorMessage, 'mess36 ');
      const latest = rejectWithValue(apiErrorMessageToTranslationKey(errorMessage));
      return latest;
    }
  },
);
```

As you may notice, the second console log which is "here2, response.data" is not visible to me.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: @markerikson can you take a look?

Answer (score 0):

Since the line where you are trying to access `error.response.data` does not log any more, I would assume `error.response` is `undefined` and your error handler crashes.

Comment: Yes. error is also returning undefined. @phry

Comment: Then something in `companiesService.create(input)` does a `throw undefined`. That's your code, seems like you have to start digging there.